# node.js inheritance prefer child constructor properties

Tags: node.js, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

```
var util = require('util');

function Entity(){
  //this.x == 10 at this point
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.globalInit();
}

Entity.prototyp.globalInit = function(){
  console.log("this.x ", x);
};

function Actor(){
  this.x = 10;
  this.y = 10;
  Actor.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}

util.inherits(Entity, Actor);
var a = new Actor();
//outputs -> this.x 0
```

I have these two constructors. I want to have the properties defined in the child constructor be the final properties. I could move `Actor.super_.apply` to the top of the constructor but there is initialization logic ( `globalInit` ) that I want to keep at the end of the parent constructor

Answer (score 1):

I can see two good solutions to this.  First, the parent constructor could take in parameters for `x` and `y`, and default them to the parent class values.

```
function Entity(x, y){
  this.x = typeof x === 'undefined' ? 0 : x;
  this.y = typeof y === 'undefined' ? 0 : y;
  this.globalInit();
}

function Actor(){
  Actor.super_.call(this, 10, 10);
}
```

This method would work best if there are not very many properties and it's not a problem to allow them to be passed in.  It breaks down somewhat if the initialization is very complex.

The second method is a bit more general in cases where you have very complicated initialization.  Essentially, you want to introduce factory methods to produce instances of the objects, which can then perform arbitrarily complex initialization.  For instance,

```
function Entity(){}
function Actor(){}

function createEntity(){
  var e = new Entity();
  e.x = 0;
  e.y = 0;
  e.globalInit();
  return e;
}

function createActor(){
  var a = new Actor();
  a.x = 10;
  a.y = 10;
  a.globalInit();
  return a;
}
```

Clearly this can be refactored to further DRY up the code, possibly with some variant of the first solution.

Using factory methods rather than directly invoking a constructor adds value in other ways as well.  It decouples the two modules somewhat, so that the consumer of these `Entities` and `Actors` doesn't need to know how to properly construct them.  It also allows you to have multiple different "constructor" signatures without painful argument analysis.